# Error migrating Flex 3 to Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, migration

I imported my Flex 3 project to Flex 4 and removed all the errors and warnings listed in Flex 4 problem windows.

I am having the following error in Flex 4 when launching my application.

What could be the cause of this?

```
Error: Compatibility version has already been read.
    at mx.core::FlexVersion$/set compatibilityVersion()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexVersion.as:254]
    at mx.core::FlexVersion$/set compatibilityVersionString()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexVersion.as:301]
    at _Screen1Module_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory()
```

Experts, please help me on this one.

Many thanks

Comment: @Constantiner

Yea indeed the prob was in modules..had to include fx namespace.

Comment: And all the modules was recompiled with the same SDK?

Comment: @flexyboz, either delete this question or answer it yourself and accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer.

The problem was actually occuring when trying to load modules in flex. So basically I included the namespaces

```
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

and also replaced `<mx:Component>`, `<mx:Style>` by their corresponding `<fx:....>`

And this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Someone having the same problem found out his FLEX_HOME environment Variable was still pointing to the flex 3 sdk.

Comment: I got it myself flexers.

It was actually not loading my modules because I didn't include the fx namespace into the module. Having done that I changed <mx:Style to <fx:Style and so on and the problem was solved.