# Compatibility version error in Flex 4

Tags: flex4

I imported a Flex 3 project to Flex 4 and removed all errors and warnings listed.

Now when launching my application, I am getting the following error:

Error: Compatibility version has already been read.
    at mx.core::FlexVersion$/set compatibilityVersion()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexVersion.as:254]
    at mx.core::FlexVersion$/set compatibilityVersionString()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\FlexVersion.as:301]
    at _MainScreen_mx_core_FlexModuleFactory()

How do I go about this one.

Help please.

Comment: Answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025649/error-migrating-flex-3-to-flex-4