# FlexVersion compatibility has already been read - _NOT_ Flex 3 to Flex 4 issue

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, fonts

To be clear, this code was working for many years using Flex 4.5.1. As such, this is *not* answered by; [Error migrating Flex 3 to Flex 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025649/error-migrating-flex-3-to-flex-4)

I am bulk generating Font CSS SWF in Flash Builder. There are nearly 700 of them, so I cannot do it in my main project, but have a related project to do so. Both projects are compiled using the same SDK (I have tried 4.6.0 (Adobe), 4.12.0 (Apache Flex), 4.13.0 (Apache Flex)).

However, since upgrading to 4.6+ from 4.5.1, I can no longer import fonts on demand as they immediately trigger `Error: Compatibility version has already been read.` error on load.

Can anybody direct me to a workaround for this?  Or explain what causes compatibility version to be written on load of SWF?

Comment: Ok, this looks like a basic build issue. It's a complex build environment and an automated process used a different SDK to the expected one. To anybody else experiencing this; check your assumptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above. This was resolved to inconsistent SDK in a complex build environment. Once everything matched (exactly) the issue disappeared.